# TestNG conditional configuration methods

Tags: testng

I would like to know if there is a way of having different configuration methods (let's say at class level, @Before/AfterClass) that will enable the user to select which configuration method to use in the testcase.
For example:

```
@BeforeClass
public void configuration1 () {
   // Do your configuration1
}

@BeforeClass
public void configuration2 () {
   // Do your configuration2
}
```

I would like to be able to select which configuration method to use. Of course, this can be done with a condition inside the configuration methods but I would like to know if I can avoid running the method that does not contain the configuration I want in a particular run.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your criteria to run a particular configuration?

Comment: For example, I can run my test with two different JVM argument values: -Dconfiguration=config1 or -Dconfiguration=config2. The first one should run my test with the first configuration method and the second with the second configuration method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TestNG provides [Listeners](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-listeners) to customize default functionality. For your requirement, [IInvokedMethodListener](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/IInvokedMethodListener.html) needs to be implemented. I don't think command line arguments can be passed to a testng xml but try your luck. In below code, "configuration" is assumed to be a parameter from testng xml.

Sample code(not tested)

```
public class CustomListener implements IInvokedMethodListener {
  @Override
  public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult itr) {
    if (method.isConfigurationMethod()) {
      String userPassed = method.getTestMethod().getXmlTest()
                .getLocalParameters().get("configuration");
      if(based on userPassed , call configuration() method){

      }
     }
   }

  @Override
  public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod arg0, ITestResult arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }
}
```

If you decide to call this Listener from your java class, then you can read the cmd line args and pass it to the CustomListener. Just an after thought.

Comment: Once the listener is ready, you can use it in different ways. See the Listeners link above for details.

Comment: Seems nice, I'll try it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your test setup you might just use groups:

```
public class Test {

  @BeforeClass(groups = {"A"})
  public void configuration1() {...}

  @BeforeClass(groups = {"B"})
  public void configuration2() {...}

  @Test(groups = {"A", "B"})
 public void testFoo() {...} 

  @Test(groups = {"A"})
  public void testFoo() {...} 
}
```

Or you might think about parameterizing your tests/use data providers.

Comment: The problem with this one is that the same test case can have different configuration methods and I need to be able to select which configuration to use when I am executing it. I do not want to have the groups hardcoded and change them each time I need to run it...