# TestNG run dependent methods every time

Tags: java, testing, junit, integration-testing, testng

I'm using TestNG 6.5.1.

So I have test methods B and C that depends on test method A. Is there a way to run method A before running method B and also again before running method C?

I know that the obvious way would be to just call the method but I don't want that because if the method A fails I don't want for method C to fail also, but to be skipped. If you have just these three methods it would seem stupid to ask for another way, but when you have a much complex dependency tree than everything changes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "dependsOnMethods" annotation on the test method.

Sample:-

```
@Test(dependsOnMethods="method2")
public void method1(){
}
```

---

Refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21233221/1662411) and change the beforeInvocation() as below,

```
public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult itr) {
if (method.isTestMethod()) {
  //call any method
}
```

}

Comment: Yeah, I know obviously about the dependsOnMethods annotation but that doesn't work like I want... By using dependsOnMethod, the method A, depended by B and C, is run only once, not before running every other method...

Comment: I resolved this by implementing a Testng MethodInterceptor. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could you change method A from a @Test to a @BeforeMethod? Then it will run before B and C and they will be skipped if it fails.