# Override @BeforeMethod in TestNG

Tags: java, testing, testng

I have a base class for all my tests with defined `@BeforeMethod` which fits to most of the tests (I am testing admin UI so I want to usually log in as an administrator before test and log out after it) - but sometimes I would like to either skip this method or override it with different one in the class which is extending my base class.

```
public class AbstractWebDriverTest {

    @BeforeMethod
    public void preparePage() {
        driver.get("somePage");
        signInAsAdmin();
    }

}

public class TestConfigWithOtherUser extends AbstractWebDriverTest {

    //now I want to skip before method and sign as a different user instead

    @Test
    public void someTestWithDifferentUser() { }

}
```

So I guess I could solve this with using groups somehow but is there a way how to override the init method?

Answer (score 1):

I would go either by grouping tests as you stated in your question or by exception. If just few cases are the exception, your test in that cases must expect, that you start as admin. My idea in Java Pseudocode:

```
 @Test
 public void someTestWithDifferentUser() {
  logout();
  logInAsDifferentUser();
  doSomeStuff();
 }
```

My other Idea is to introduce `User` class which could look like this:

```
public class User{
  private String username;
  private String password;

  public User(String username, String password){
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
  }

  public String getUsername(){
    return username;
  }   

  public String getPassword(){
    return password;
  }

}
```

Then, in your tests you would have one global variable:

```
public static final User DEFAULT_USER = new User("admin","AdminSecretPassword");
```

and your tests would look like this:

```
@Test
public void doAdminStuff(){
 loginAsUser(DEFAULT_USER);
 doAdminStuff;
}

@Test
public void doUserStuff(){
 loginAsUser(new User("testytester","testytest"));
 doUserStuff();
}
```

Where the `@BeforeMethod` would avoid the login completly.

Comment: First option looks ok - although I would like to avoid code repetition in every test which is different, that's why method overriding would be nice because you would have one method with initial settings for the whole class.

Comment: It really depends on your setup: If you have 100 cases from which 5 are for different user, then go by my example. If there is 20 for different user, I would try to go for some tests grouping

Comment: There will be just few of them which seems to me that I should go for grouping in order to avoid pollution of the "default" tests with redundant code...

Answer (score 1):

You can use Listeners interface to override default behaviour. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21233221/1662411) post which had a similar requirement to yours.

```
public class SkipLoginMethodListener implements IInvokedMethodListener {

private static final String SKIP_GROUP = "loginMethod";

@Override
public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod invokedMethod, ITestResult testResult) {
    ITestNGMethod method = invokedMethod.getTestMethod();
    if (method.isAfterMethodConfiguration() || method.isBeforeMethodConfiguration()) {
        for (String group : method.getGroups()) {
            if (group.equals(SKIP_GROUP)) {
                System.out.println("skipped " + method.getMethodName());
                throw new SkipException("Configuration of the method " + method.getMethodName() + " skipped");
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you, the listener works but I just don't know how skip the method I want. I put configuration methods into one you group and whenever I attach this listener to the test class I want to skip those methods. I tried throwing `SkipException` but this skips all the tests too.

Comment: I've edited your answer with my code, feel free to update it, thank you!